# Hex to Decimal Conversion - PowerShell 5

Tags: powershell, hex

For some reason, when converting some values in PowerShell from Hex to Decimal, I get incorrect value.

For example:
- Type `0xC0000000` then hit enter, you'll get `-1073741824` which is incorrect, the right value is `3221225472`. The answer given is the value for the negative Hex number I entered `FFFFFFFFC0000000`

I thought this could be an interpretation issue so I explicitly asked to convert the value to from Hex to Base10 (Decimal), I still got the same incorrect answer `-1073741824`:

```
[Convert]::ToString(0xc0000000,10)
```

Why does PowerShell interpret `0xc0000000` as the negative for the Hex number `c0000000`? am I missing something here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a PowerShell gotcha (exists in earlier versions too). The value is interpreted as a signed integer when you actually want it to be an unsigned integer. You need to do the conversion like this to get around the issue:

```
[uint32]"0xC0000000"
```

Comment: Weird `[uint32]0xC0000000` doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Ansgar [already provided the work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38567654/503046), but some explanation about what's going on might be of interest.

The root cause for this phenomenon is caused by the binary system. It doesn't really have a concept of negative numbers. There are just bits: series of ones and zeros. In order to interpret a number as either positive or negative, [creative trickery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) has been invented.

What happens in your case is that `0xC <=> 12dec <=> 1100 bin`. Thus, as the first bit is one, the bit pattern is interpreted as negative value and you get `-1073741824` as the result. This, by the way, is the reason why some Windows' error messages contain nonsensical negative error codes.

Comment: That is basically what I meant by "interpreted as a signed integer". ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This makes it clearer why the signed int was considered a negative number as I thought the most left 16th digit is what would be used but after reading this, I now get it. Windows does some funky stuff sometimes.